# Dynamic conditional statement in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

Is there a way in which I can write a dynamic conditional statement. For example, I want to see that my data can be grouped by 50 or 100 by just tipping the value 50 or 100.

```
table = generate(1,9000000, 0.01)
```

Here there is an example, when I want to group the data by 50

```
= Table.AddColumn(one_pm_test_lm_5_sek_xyl_1_Table, "XLenght bin", each if
 [XLength] >= 500 then "500 and above" 
else if [XLength] >= 450 then "450 - 500"
 else if [XLength] >= 400 then "400 - 450"
 else if [XLength] >= 350 then "350 - 400"
 else if [XLength] >= 300 then "300 - 350"
 else if [XLength] >= 250 then "250 - 300" 
else if [XLength] >= 200 then "200 - 250" 
else if [XLength] >= 150 then "150 - 200" 
else if [XLength] >= 100 then "100 - 150"
 else if [XLength] >= 50 then "50 - 100" 
else "50 or below")
```

I try to create a dynamic function or something like that which makes posible that I group the data for example in 50. Until now, I make it manually. I would like to know if there is another way to do it in order to enter the values manually.

```
XLength Group = SWITCH(TRUE(),
[XLength] < 50, "<50",
[XLength] <= 100, "50-100",
[XLength] <= 150, "100-150",
[XLength] <= 200, "150-200",
[XLength] <= 250, "200-250",
[XLength] <= 300, "250-300",
[XLength] <= 350, "300-350",
[XLength] <= 400, "350-400",
[XLength] <= 450, "400-450",
[XLength] <= 500, "450-500",
[XLength] > 500, "500+")
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The table and data model can be evaluated only while data loading or refreshing.  Tables evaluates first, then links, then visuals. You can work with dynamic values only with visuals like matrix/table using DAX.

Comment: My intenton is to create a slicer which regulates the bind in a histogram. I do not know if I explain it very well

Comment: So, you want to use a measure for a histogram visual and use a slicer to show result for different groups upon selection. It's possible. The last piece of the puzzle what exactly you want to show with histogram -Ox,Oy and number of what?

Comment: @DavidBacci I added something  below to clarify my post

Comment: https://radacad.com/dynamic-banding-or-grouping-in-power-bi-using-dax-measures-choose-the-count-of-bins

Comment: The problem is Ox. You can't change it dynamically, It can be hierarchy with all possible "weights" as a solution, or you can make a supportive table with a column where values are all possible "weights" and use it as Ox with displaying of not blank values. Or you can  use graduation and if you will select for instance 40 then you will get non blank values on 40 (x<=40), 80 (40<x<=80) etc. but you should keep this rule always in mind that is not good. At least you need to select how Ox will be created 1 scale for all cases.